# can't deplopy to github pages with pnpm?

Tags: deployment, github-actions, github-pages, pnpm

i am new to github actions and made a recent question here on stackoverflow got the part i needed answered but endup facing another issue the script won't deploy and give the final url.

```
name: pnpm Example Workflow
on:
push:
jobs:
 build:
 runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   strategy:
    matrix:
     node-version: [18]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2
       with:
       version: 7
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
       with:
       node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
       cache: 'pnpm'
    - name: Install dependencies
       run: pnpm install
    - name: Build
       run: pnpm run build
   deploy:
   environment:
     name: github-pages
    #  url: ${{steps.deployment.outputs.page_url}}
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

 - name: Setup Pages
   uses: actions/configure-pages@v3
 - name: Upload artifact
    uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
    with:
     # Upload dist repository
    path: .
  - name: Deploy
   - name: Deploy
     uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
      with:
     github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      publish_dir: ./public
```

something went wrong along the way and i don't know how to proceed from here
can any one pin point my mistake

edit:
after i formated script i got this error :

`deploy  Environment URL '' is not a valid http(s) URL, so it will not be    shown as a link in the workflow graph.`

Comment: There are multiple syntax errors in your workflow. Use https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ and fix them one-by-one.

Comment: after i formated script i got this error 

deploy
Environment URL '' is not a valid http(s) URL, so it will not be shown as a link in the workflow graph.

Comment: Please edit and update your question with these new details. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 name: pnpm Example Workflow
on:
  push: 
  branches: [ master]

 permissions:
   contents: read
   pages: write
   id-token: write

 jobs:
   build:
    environment:
    name: github-pages
  url: ${{steps.deployment.outputs.page_url}}
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

strategy:
  matrix:
    node-version: [18]
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2
    with:
      version: 7
  - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    uses: actions/setup-node@v3
    with:
      node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      cache: pnpm
  - name: Install dependencies
    run: pnpm install
  - name: Build
    run: pnpm run build
  - name: Setup Pages
    uses: actions/configure-pages@v3
  - name: Upload artifact
    uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
    with:
      # Upload dist repository
       path: ./dist
  - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
    id: deployment
    uses: actions/deploy-pages@v1
```

This is the solution to my question